# Wordpress multisite redirect 302 after migration

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a multisite on my localhost, i did migration to pre-production server (changed databases etc ...) and it works well. Today i did migration to production server and like pre-production i chanded all urls from database, wp-config but now i get 302 redirections (https to http).

Someone had already this issue? i checked google and some guys suggests me to add some constants to wp-config :

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

to clear cookie, but this not working either, below are my wp-config and my htaccess contents :

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.domain.com/mymultisite');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
//...
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

// htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What i did wrong? thank you

Comment: Don't forget to restart the apache server after editing htaccess @sandy

Answer (score 1):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status
> response code indicates that the resource requested has been
> temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header.

1- Try to restore the default `htaccess` file.

2- Try to deactivate all the themes and plugins, and you can do it 1 by 1.

3- Check all the url's in the database, and try to use a plugin to edit all the links in the DB.

4- If nothing helps try to check the website from different pc or computer.

5- Check this [topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170165/wordpress-wp-admin-https-redirect-loop), it might help you with the same subject.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, i already checked urls in db using search and replace tool of interconnectit, deactivate plugins, theme is custom

Comment: @Sandy I know this is long ago, but did you resolve the issue?